# Naming a function that applies a list of functions to one value

Tags: functional-programming, naming

But how do you call a function that takes a [X -> Y] and a X and gives back a [Y]? I.e. a function that takes a list of functions and a value and gives back a list of results when all functions from the list are applied to the given argument.

Most of the common simple higher order functions have consisent simple names in most programming languages:

- If a function takes [X] and f: X -> Y and gives back a [Y}, then it's commonly called map. (Sometimes it's a method, sometimes a function, but the principle is always the same)
- If a function takes a [X] and a f: X -> boolean and gives back a [X] it's called filter.
- If a function takes a [X] and a f: X -> [Y] and gives backa [Y], it's called flatMap.

Note that it is of course trivial to implement this in any language that has support for functional programming and that's not my question. My question is about naming. I haven't found any language that has this built in, so I couldn't copy the name from anywhere. But it feels like this is such a basic thing that there should be a globally understood name.

Comment: Isn't that just a Map-FlatMap composition?

Comment: `sequence` in Haskell does this.

Comment: Clojure calls this [`juxt'](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/juxt), short for "juxtaposition".

Answer (score 1):

Functions have type too. A function of type `a -> b` has a different type than a function of type `a -> c`.

So, you have a function `x -> y`. For conceptual sake, we'll call that type `z`. And you have a list of these `z`-type functions, but you want a list of `y`, so you need `[z] -> [y]` – which is exactly what `map` does.

If we expand `z` back to our original type, `x -> y`, we can see the final type of the function we're trying to make: `[x -> y] -> [y]`. All that's left is getting from `x -> y` to `y`. Let's see `apply` –

```js
// apply : a -> (a -> b) -> b
const apply = x => f =>
  f (x)
```

If we give `apply` an argument, it gives us back a function of the exact type you're looking for –

```js
apply (2)        // : (Number -> b) -> b
apply ("hello")  // : (String -> b) -> b
```

Combining `map` and `apply` we achieve our result –

```js
// apply : a -> (a -> b) -> b
const apply = x => f =>
  f (x)

// mult : Number -> Number -> Number  
const mult = x => y =>
  x * y
  
// listOfFuncs : [ Number -> Number ]
const listOfFuncs =
  [ mult (1)         // : Number -> Number
  , mult (2)         // : Number -> Number
  , mult (3)         // : Number -> Number
  , mult (4)         // : Number -> Number
  ]
  
console .log
  ( listOfFuncs .map (apply (2))   // [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ] : [ Number ]
  , listOfFuncs .map (apply (10))  // [ 10, 20, 30, 40 ] : [ Number ]
  )
```

I've never seen a unique name given to this particular combination of functions, but I don't think it needs one either. `map` and `apply` are both simple and I think they encode your intention directly.

---

Another way to approach this might be to deconstruct your question first. *"Naming a function that applies a list of functions to one value"* is an over-stated need if you already have a function that takes a list of one type and produces a list of a new type (`map`). The unique need here is the ability to apply a constant to a function, which we saw was easily shown with `apply`.

Combining effects of simple programs is what makes functional programming powerful. Writing a program that does too many things make it less reusable. Struggling to name a function can be an indicator that you're making a misstep.